# Rotate objects in specific relation to one another

Tags: animation, drivers

Okay, think of an analog clock, as an easy point of reference. I rotate the minute hand 360 degrees on the X-axis. Can I somehow couple the performed rotation of the minute hand to the hour hand in such a way, that would let the hour hand rotate exactly 30 degrees every time the minute hand rotates 360? Preferably in a linear and not a constant way, if that makes sense. Meaning that the hour hand moves as the minute hand moves and not suddenly jumps 30 degrees once the minute hand made a full rotation.

Disclaimer: I know, this is highly unnecessary, as one could just rotate the hands individually at the required pace, but I am still curious if something like that is possible and in how many layers it would be, if we were not only talking about a clock, but a gear box for example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a driver for the hour hand, right click on its rotation angle (I've chosen Y) value and > *Add Driver*, in the pop-up type *Expression > var/12*, select the minute hand as *Object* and *Type > Y Rotation*:

[image]

Result:

[image]